# Identifying events in timeseries Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I am trying to identify events in a timeseries Pandas dataframe. An event is when a value is non-zero for more than 30 seconds. An event can contain values that equal 0 as long as the values are not 0 for a consecutive 30 seconds or longer. If an event is shorter than 30 seconds and is surrounded by zeroes, it is not an event. An event ends at the last non-zero value where the following values are zero for 30 seconds or more. I want the output to look something like the Events column in the reprex.

Reprex:

```
import pandas as pd


Timestamp = pd.date_range("11-30-2023 23:54:00", periods = 63, freq = "5s")
Value=[0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.0,0.0,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.5,0.5,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0]
Events = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0] 
df = pd.DataFrame({"Timestamp":Timestamp, "Value":Value, "Events":Events})
```

Comment: Can you clarify how zeros can be present in an event since your definition of an event is "*An event is when a value is non-zero for more than 30 seconds*"

Comment: I guess that's a caveat to the definition. An event then can be defined as a group of rows that starts at a non-zero value if there are at least 30 seconds of zero values before that value. an event ends at the last non-zero value before a 30-second series of values that equal 0. in this definition, there may be values that equal zero in an event, so long as those values are not consecutive across more than 30 seconds of time. To see this in the data, notice how rows 0:25 are all a part of the same event, even though rows 8:10 and 18:19 contain values that equal 0.

Comment: got it, then you can use a variant of my approach below. Let me update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First identify the chunks of ≥30s of 0s, mask them, then form groups in between and determine if the duration is ≥30s:

```
# identify null values
m = df['Value'].eq(0)
# group consecutive
group = (~m).cumsum()

# compute the duration of the chunks of zeros
zero_chunks = df.loc[m, 'Timestamp'].groupby(group).agg(np.ptp)

# identify chunks ≥ 30s
zero_chunks_gt_30s = zero_chunks[zero_chunks.ge('30s')].index

# identify external zeros
external_zeros = m.cummin() | m[::-1].cummin()

# exclude 0s that are external or part of a chunks ≥ 30s
excluded = group.isin(zero_chunks_gt_30s)&m|external_zeros

# form groups in between, identify those ≥ 30s
df['Events'] = (df.loc[~excluded, 'Timestamp']
                   .groupby(excluded.cumsum())
                   .transform(lambda x: np.ptp(x)>=pd.Timedelta('30s'))
                   .reindex(df.index, fill_value=0)
                   .astype(int)
                )
```

*NB. the output is identical to the provided one.*

Output:

```
             Timestamp  Value  Events
0  2023-11-30 23:54:00    0.5       1
1  2023-11-30 23:54:05    0.5       1
2  2023-11-30 23:54:10    0.5       1
3  2023-11-30 23:54:15    0.5       1
4  2023-11-30 23:54:20    0.5       1
5  2023-11-30 23:54:25    0.5       1
6  2023-11-30 23:54:30    0.5       1
7  2023-11-30 23:54:35    0.5       1
8  2023-11-30 23:54:40    0.0       1
9  2023-11-30 23:54:45    0.0       1
10 2023-11-30 23:54:50    0.0       1
11 2023-11-30 23:54:55    0.5       1
12 2023-11-30 23:55:00    0.5       1
13 2023-11-30 23:55:05    0.5       1
14 2023-11-30 23:55:10    0.5       1
15 2023-11-30 23:55:15    0.5       1
16 2023-11-30 23:55:20    0.5       1
17 2023-11-30 23:55:25    0.5       1
18 2023-11-30 23:55:30    0.0       1
19 2023-11-30 23:55:35    0.0       1
20 2023-11-30 23:55:40    0.5       1
21 2023-11-30 23:55:45    0.5       1
22 2023-11-30 23:55:50    0.5       1
23 2023-11-30 23:55:55    0.5       1
24 2023-11-30 23:56:00    0.5       1
25 2023-11-30 23:56:05    0.5       1
26 2023-11-30 23:56:10    0.0       0
27 2023-11-30 23:56:15    0.0       0
28 2023-11-30 23:56:20    0.0       0
29 2023-11-30 23:56:25    0.0       0
30 2023-11-30 23:56:30    0.0       0
31 2023-11-30 23:56:35    0.0       0
32 2023-11-30 23:56:40    0.0       0
33 2023-11-30 23:56:45    0.0       0
34 2023-11-30 23:56:50    0.0       0
35 2023-11-30 23:56:55    0.0       0
36 2023-11-30 23:57:00    0.5       0
37 2023-11-30 23:57:05    0.5       0
38 2023-11-30 23:57:10    0.0       0
39 2023-11-30 23:57:15    0.0       0
40 2023-11-30 23:57:20    0.0       0
41 2023-11-30 23:57:25    0.0       0
42 2023-11-30 23:57:30    0.0       0
43 2023-11-30 23:57:35    0.0       0
44 2023-11-30 23:57:40    0.0       0
45 2023-11-30 23:57:45    0.0       0
46 2023-11-30 23:57:50    0.0       0
47 2023-11-30 23:57:55    0.0       0
48 2023-11-30 23:58:00    0.5       1
49 2023-11-30 23:58:05    0.5       1
50 2023-11-30 23:58:10    0.5       1
51 2023-11-30 23:58:15    0.5       1
52 2023-11-30 23:58:20    0.5       1
53 2023-11-30 23:58:25    0.5       1
54 2023-11-30 23:58:30    0.5       1
55 2023-11-30 23:58:35    0.5       1
56 2023-11-30 23:58:40    0.5       1
57 2023-11-30 23:58:45    0.5       1
58 2023-11-30 23:58:50    0.5       1
59 2023-11-30 23:58:55    0.0       0
60 2023-11-30 23:59:00    0.0       0
61 2023-11-30 23:59:05    0.0       0
62 2023-11-30 23:59:10    0.0       0
```

Comment: I'm confused by the `drop` variable inside .isin(). Is that supposed to be `zero_chunks_gt_30s` ?

Comment: @Sam yes, sorry, I changed the name to make it more explicit ;)

Comment: this is a great answer. adding some NaN handling and changing the time duration to variables (30sec, etc.) for my purposes. Very nice solution, thanks! I'm surprised there weren't more questions around this. Seems like it would be common to try to identify "events" in time series data